# How can one obtain an Access Token in Swagger Editor/Frontend when consuming APIs that are published in the WSO2 API Manager publisher portal?

Tags: curl, frontend, swagger-ui, access-token, wso2-api-manager

I have published API in WSO2 API Manager. I can access the same in DevPortal. In WSO2 Portals we get an access token on a click.
[Image showing interface to get access token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtC7r.png)

How to obtain an access token in Swagger Editor when consuming APIs?
[Swagger Definition downloaded from Developer Portal and imported in Swagger Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6zTx.png)

I want to know how I can use the APIs published in WSO2 API Manager in Frontend or Swagger Editor. Because I am not getting how to obtain Access Token which is required to consume APIs.

I tried modifying the Swagger file(Downloaded from Developer Portal) so that I can get Access Token using the cURL command (by executing it in the command prompt).

[I can enter the access token here and is working but I need to obtain the token from the command prompt. I don't think it's a reliable approach to proceed with.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhjmB.png)

Above mentioned approach will not be feasible while using APIs in Frontend.

Comment: Have you checked the WSO2 API Manager docs on how to consume the API? You'll have to create an Application in the Devportal and then have to subscribe to that API. Once, you have subscribed, you can generate the Access Token using the OAuth2 protocol and use it to invoke the API. Please find the docs [1](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/consume/consume-api-overview/) [2](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/consume/manage-application/create-application/) [3](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/consume/manage-subscription/subscribe-to-an-api/)